# Chrome extension content script not seeing AJAX loaded content

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Im trying to develop a Chrome Extension that can display the images on a web page to a user to let them clip them, similar to what Pinterest's Pin It extension does.

The problem is, when I use the extension on a page that is loaded images dynamically, such as Pinterest on page scroll, the content script doesnt appear to find those images.   In fact its not always finding the same images each time I run it.

How do I get my Chrome Extension to scrape all of the CURRENT elements on the page, including those updated with AJAX?

The below code is designed specifically to grab images from a Pinterest board.

**Manifest.json**

```
{
  "name" : "clipper",
  "version" : "0.1",
  "description" : "Captures images from page.",
  "browser_action": {
     "default_icon": "icon.png",
     "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": ["js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js", "js/content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Content.js**

```
// content.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if( request.subject === "getImages" ) {
      var imgs = getAllImages();

      sendResponse(imgs);
    }
  }
);

function getAllImages() {
  var $imgs, imgs = [], imgCount = 0;;

  $imgs = $('.pinUiImage img')
  $imgs.each(function(ndx, el) {
    if (imgCount < 500) {
      var $el = $(el), img = {}, theImage = new Image();

      img.src = $el.prop('src');

      // in case location.href doesnt return a value in UIWebKit
      var source = window.location.href;
      if (source === undefined) {
        source = document.URL;
      }

      if (img.src !== undefined && source !== undefined) {
        theImage.src = img.src;

        img.dWidth = $el.width();
        img.dHeight = $el.height();
        img.width = theImage.width;
        img.height = theImage.height;
        img.source = source;
        img.name = $el.attr('title') || $el.attr('alt') || document.title;

        // if (img.dWidth >= 200 && img.dHeight >= 200) {
        //   if (img.src.indexOf('data:image') != 0) {
        //     // neat trick to standardize a url using jquery
        //     var a = $('<a>', { href:img.src } )[0];
        //     img.src = a.href;
        //   }
        //   imgs.push(img);
        //   imgCount++;
        // }

        imgs.push(img);
        imgCount++;
      } else {
        console.log('source undefined')
      }
    }
  });

  return imgs;  
}
```

**Popup.js**

```
function setImageDisplay (imgs) {
  console.log(imgs);

  var $imgs, $div;
  $imgs = $('#images')
  $div = $("<h1 class='count'>Images Found: "+imgs.length+"</h1>");
  $('body').prepend($div);


  $.each(imgs, function(ndx, img) {
    var $div = $("<div class='image'></div>"), 
      $img = $("<img/>");

    $img.attr('src', img.src);

    $div.append($img);
    $imgs.append($div);
  })
}

/* Once the DOM is ready... */
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    /* ...query for the active tab... */
    chrome.tabs.query({
        active: true,
        currentWindow: true
    }, function(tabs) {
        /* ...and send a request for the DOM info... */
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(
                tabs[0].id,
                {from: 'popup', subject: 'getImages'},
                /* ...also specifying a callback to be called 
                 *    from the receiving end (content script) */
                setImageDisplay);
    });
});
```

**Popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Wecora</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="images"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code seems correct - it should return images that are in the document at the moment you open the popup. Are you certain your _selector_ is correct for all images, including loaded dynamically?

Comment: @xan yes the selector is correct, which is why I can see the first page of images. Not sure why it doesn't see more when run after more images are loaded.

Comment: @teepeemm what do you mean reload the content script from a background page?  I thought the listener I have is only triggered when the browser action button is clicked, so not sure how a background page would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: If you manually run that selector in the page, does it return everything you expect? Maybe it is invalid after dynamic loading. Also, are you sure you're not hitting the 500 limit in your code?

Comment: @Xan Sorry but what's the 500 limit and yes that should capture all images.  Try it on a Pinterest board and you'll see.

Comment: See your code. It collects images while `(imgCount < 500)` holds.

Comment: @Xan ah you mean my 500 limit. No, it only captures the first 20-50 and then stops.